# Ruby mechanize post with header

Tags: ruby, xmlhttprequest, mechanize

I have page with js that post data via XMLHttpRequest and server side script check for this header, how to send this header?

```
agent = WWW::Mechanize.new { |a|
  a.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
  a.log = Logger.new('./site.log')
}

agent.post('http://site.com/board.php',
  {
    'act' => '_get_page',
    "gid" => 1,
    'order' => 0,
    'page' => 2
  }
) do |page|
  p page
end
```

Comment: What header is the server side script looking for? It can vary. For example, in Rails I believe _method is looked for, but that's not necessarily going to be the case with whatever PHP script you're hitting.

Comment: I think you need to accept an answer AnimalCode...

Answer (score 11):

I found this post with a web search (two months later, I know) and just wanted to share another solution.

You can add custom headers without monkey patching Mechanize using a pre-connect hook:

```
  agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
  agent.pre_connect_hooks << lambda { |p|
    p[:request]['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }
```

Comment: I came here looking for a way to set the Referer header.  However with _mechanize (2.3)_ I get the error `undefined method 'pre_connect_hooks' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @marcos: that would suggest that your `agent` object is nil for some reasons.  Can you check that?  Once you fix that, you'll find that Mechanize 2.0 takes different arguments for the lambda -- check the latest docs.

Comment: My comment is no longer valid after I edited this answer. Previously I coded it erroneously as one long line as presented in ver.1, causing `agent.pre_connect_hooks` to get used prior to `agent` getting defined.

Comment: Gives me `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`, mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:398:in `call'. Used http://stackoverflow.com/a/30266454/111995 insted

Answer (score 8):

```
ajax_headers = { 'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Accept' => 'application/json, text/javascript, */*'}
params = {'emailAddress' => 'me@my.com'}.to_json
response = agent.post( 'http://example.com/login', params, ajax_headers)
```

The above code works for me (Mechanize 1.0) as a way to make the server think the request is coming via AJAX, but as stated in other answers it depends what the server is looking for, it will be different for different frameworks/js library combos.

The best thing to do is use Firefox [HTTPLiveHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) plugin or [HTTPScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/) and look at the request headers sent by the browser and just try and replicate that.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like earlier that lambda had one argument, but now it has two:

```
agent = Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.pre_connect_hooks << lambda do |agent, request|
    request["Accept-Language"] = "ru"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/WWW/Mechanize.html).

You need to either monkey-patch or derive your own class from `WWW::Mechanize` to override the `post` method so that custom headers are passed through to the private method `post_form`.

For example,

```
class WWW::Mechanize
  def post(url, query= {}, headers = {})
    node = {}
    # Create a fake form
    class << node
      def search(*args); []; end
    end
    node['method'] = 'POST'
    node['enctype'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

    form = Form.new(node)
    query.each { |k,v|
      if v.is_a?(IO)
        form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data'
        ul = Form::FileUpload.new(k.to_s,::File.basename(v.path))
        ul.file_data = v.read
        form.file_uploads << ul
      else
        form.fields << Form::Field.new(k.to_s,v)
      end
    }
    post_form(url, form, headers)
  end
end

agent = WWW::Mechanize.new

agent.post(URL,POSTDATA,{'custom-header' => 'custom'}) do |page|
    p page
end
```