# How to set the Referer header before loading a page with Ruby mechanize?

Tags: ruby, http-headers, mechanize, http-referer

Is there a straightforward way to set custom headers with Mechanize 2.3?

I tried a [former solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536251/1069375) but get:

```
$agent = Mechanize.new
$agent.pre_connect_hooks << lambda { |p|
  p[:request]['Referer'] = 'https://wwws.mysite.com/cgi-bin/apps/Main'
} 

# ./mech.rb:30:in `<main>': undefined method `pre_connect_hooks' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the question itself, and it is a valid one, so I kept it. Even posted an answer for others who'd get stumped on the same thing.  Another issue is merely masking the actual problem with mechanize I seem to be facing. but otherwise unrelated to this here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The docs](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html) say:

```
get(uri, parameters = [], referer = nil, headers = {}) { |page| ... }
```

so for example:

```
agent.get 'http://www.google.com/', [], agent.page.uri, {'foo' => 'bar'}
```

alternatively you might like:

```
agent.request_headers = {'foo' => 'bar'}
agent.get url
```

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood the code you were copying. There was a newline in the example, but it disappeared in the formatting as it wasn't tagged as code. `$agent` contains `nil` since you're trying to use it before it has been initialized. You must initialize the object and then use it. Just try this:

```rb
$agent = Mechanize.new
$agent.pre_connect_hooks << lambda { |p| p[:request]['Referer'] = 'https://wwws.mysite.com/cgi-bin/apps/Main' }
```

Answer (score 1):

For this question I noticed people seem to use:

```
page = agent.get("http://www.you.com/index_login/", :referer => "http://www.you.com/")
```

As an aside, now that I tested this answer, it seems this was not the issue behind my actual problem: that every visit to a site I'm scraping requires going through the login sequence pages again, even seconds later after the first logged-in visit, despite that I'm always loading and saving the complete cookie jar in yaml format. But that would lead to another question of course.

Comment: You shouldn't accept your own answer, furthermore your answer is not right, you should choose pguardiario answer

Comment: As you suggest, I switched answers (now in 2019), although I haven't confirmed nor tested it; that environment is long gone.  Back in 2012, my eventual solution was the only one that worked for me among others, if any.  There is a lot to be said about the effects of libraries and even APIs changing their behavior & nuances over time.  I.e. what used to be "right" nearly eight years ago...