# How to get request headers using Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I want to get the request headers that were sent by Mechanize during the HTTP request:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}
page = a.get('http://www.example.com/')
```

I need the request headers cause my page has a redirection of 2/3 times and interim of the redirection, it added few headers in it.

Comment: did you try logging the mechanize calls?

Comment: added `a.log = Logger.new "mech.log"` and seems lot of useful information is availed to the log file. it fulfilled my purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to run a `pre_connect_hooks` to get the request header

```
 agent.pre_connect_hooks << lambda do |agent, request|
   request['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
 end
```

Check this thread [so-1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10129025/1225337)

**Read Response Header**

```
puts page.header['location']
puts page.header['server']
```

loop through the header array